# Oracle SQL column show misalignments

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table (columns C1, C2 and C3) and would like to generate column C4 based on the misalignments of columns C1, C2, C3. Is there any way of obtaining this in a escalable way (in case I need to do it for n columns in the future) without going with a case when scenario by scenario?

| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | A1 | null | MISMATCH_C3 |
| A2 | A2 | A2 | CORRECT |
| null | null | null | NULLS |
| A4 | A1 | A3 | MISMATCH_ALL |
| A5 | A1 | 87 | MISMATCH_ALL |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a giant `case` expression.  Something like this:

```
(case when c1 <> c2 and c2 <> c3 and c3 <> c1
      then 'MISMATCH_ALL'
      when c1 is null and c2 is null and c3 is null
      then 'NULLS'
      when c1 = c2 and c2 = c3
      then 'CORRECT'
      when c1 = c2
      then 'MISMATCH_C3'
      when c1 = c3
      then 'MISMATCH_C2'
      when c2 = c3
      then 'MISMATCH_C1'
      else 'Other -- probably 2 NULLs'
 end)
```

There is no "scalable" way of doing this if you store the data in columns.  It sounds like this data should be stored in *rows* not *columns*.  If that were the case, then you could do something with aggregation.

The data should be stored as:

```
ENTITY_ID     colnum       value
    1            1          'A1'
    1            2          'A1'
    1            3          NULL
    2            1          'A2'
    . . .
```

Then it would be trivial to add new "columns".  And you can adjust the logic to return the information you want.

Comment: What do you mean by storing the data in rows? Could you put an example?

Comment: With the latest edit: how could I compare the logic among values in a scalable way?

Comment: @JaviTorre . . . You would start by asking a new question.  This question has been answered.